# What could be the reason that an app can get stuck at Binding.inflate which previously works fine?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding

After realizing that my app seems to be miss behaving, I did some clever debugging tactics, namely adding `Log` calls between my code and some cheeky debug breakpoints, I realized that my `MainActivity` doesn't seem to get past the `binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)` line on my code. And I'm not getting any error as well. The relevant code are these lines:

```
Log.d(TAG, "before mainActBind")
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
Log.d(TAG, "after mainActBind")
setContentView(binding.root)
Log.d(TAG, "after setContent")
setSupportActionBar(binding.appContentMain.toolbar)
Log.d(TAG, "after setSupportActionBar")
```

Those are the top-most lines code inside my `MainActivity`'s `onCreate`, I still have `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` there as well.

And what I'm getting in Logcat looks like this:

```
RenderThread::setGrContext()
Checking for metadata for AppLocalesMetadataHolderService : Service not found
Access denied finding property "vendor.mali.config"
RenderThread::setGrContext()
Checking for metadata for AppLocalesMetadataHolderService : Service not found
before mainActBind
Compat change id reported: 210923482; UID 10259; state: ENABLED
Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;-><init>(Ljava/lang/Class;I)V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
```

I'm currently running Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1 Patch 1. I already did Invalidate Caches, Clean, Rebuild and Make Project.

I already tried using `DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)`, but it doesn't seem to work

Here's what my activity_main.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

    </data>

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_content_main"
            layout="@layout/app_content_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, I already found the issue. Essentially, my `Fragment`s were waiting for something that was about to get initialized in `MainActivity` and those waiting code blocked everything from executing including the initialization of the class that they need. So, I moved those waiting code to `onStart` and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your XML layout file have no error.

And you could try to add  tag in your XML file

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
    </data>
</layout>
```

Comment: Well, my activity_main.xml is quite simple, so I don't think that the cause of the issue. I'll add the the layout on my question